# Reaction-diffusion parallel growing method

Tags: algorithm, math, formula, nonlinear-functions, chaos

I've created many types of reaction-diffusion patterns using different parameters for death and feed rates etc. Working with them on Ready by GollyGang (a simple C++ software that can grow the patterns based on parameters and code) However, they all end up in curly, combined, maze-like forms, or dots etc. Like this:

[image]

What I want to achieve though is more like parallel, straight lines that occasionaly combine looking like veins or growing branches; see the image below:

[image]

I've searched for any formula for this but couldn't find any. What parameters should I play with?

Comment: Do you necessarily need precise solutions or just schematic ones that _look_ similar

Comment: I can create the directional growth by adding motion blur in Photoshop, but I'd like to explore it dynamically on Ready. @willywonkadailyblah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Gray-Scott reaction-diffusion system, have a look near k=0.0625, F=0.045:

[image: Gray-Scott reaction-diffusion system in Ready]

On a sphere it looks like this:

[image]

I don't know how they've done the nice spiral though. Perhaps painting into the image is enough to nudge it along. Or you might need to draw an initial pattern. Or perhaps you have to apply a constant bias to the direction of the lines.

Ready: https://github.com/GollyGang/ready

Gray-Scott parameter map: http://mrob.com/pub/comp/xmorphia/

Link to the Nervous System lampshade shown in the question: http://n-e-r-v-o-u-s.com/shop/product.php?code=66&search=lighting